# Wordpress ошибка ответа сайта 500 при создании functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Создаю тему с нуля, все ОК работает, но как только создаю файл functions.php (пустой) - сайт перестает работать и выдает ошибку 500, даже в панели администратора. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А попробуйте не пустой, хотя бы php тег там создать ‘<?php’ и проблема должна уйти. Тег должен быть в первой строке, без всяких пробелов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле wp-config включи debug, потом обнови страницу на сайте и после чего в папке wp-content появится файл debug.log, там и будет написана причина ошибки.

Тут это 6той способ:

https://www.hostinger.com.ua/rukovodstva/kak-ispravit-oshibku-500#-5

Если файла не появится в папке, то включите просмотреть скрытые файлы и папки, если используете FileZilla

Answer (score 0):

одного functions.php при создании темы не достаточно, должен быть еще style.css